# Connection with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, properties, database-connection

I'm trying to create a connection with database mySQL but it results in such a different error:

```
public class DBConfig {
    private String url;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;
    private String database;


    public DBConfig(){
        try (FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("src/utils/db.properties")){
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fs);
            this.url = properties.getProperty("url");
            this.usuario = properties.getProperty("user");
            this.senha = properties.getProperty("password");
            this.database = properties.getProperty("database");
        } catch (IOException erro) {
              System.out.println(erro.getMessage());
        }
    }

...


import aulas.conexao.db.DBConfig;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConfig db = new DBConfig();
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db.getUrl()
                    ,db.getUsuario()
                    , db.getSenha());
            System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso!");
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
              try{
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste", "root", "123456789");
                  System.out.println("conexão realizada com sucesso!");
                  con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the first try block results in Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) error. the second try block works even the params are the same as the first one.

I've tried all the solutions on YouTube, articles but nothing solves the problem.

EDIT:
the db.properties content [db.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCmpX.png)

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTRCI.png)

Comment: most probably the parameters are not the same - at very least print them or use a debugger to confirm their content - such question better include a [mre] and the input data (and as I always say, prefer written tutorials, video tutorials are not the best for teaching/learning how to program)

Comment: for example, are you sure that `getUrl()` is really returning `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste"`  and not just `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"` (missing database?) Or that `getPassword()` is returning the correct value (based on error message?)

Comment: Tip: [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) and [an implementation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/270786/19079)

Comment: Please post the content of db.properties as text not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when reading data from a file or other resource, it is better to use `trim()` format the data. Otherwise, some strange problems will show up. Even though your debug image shows that the password is the same as the catch part.

Consider changing your code like this:

```java
this.senha = properties.getProperty("password").trim();
```